# Do Native program adresses should also be passed into the transaction?

Tags: native-programs

I have reached the maximum transaction size and looking for a way to reduce the number of 32bytes addresses involved.

I see the proposal being accepted but not implemented https://docs.solana.com/proposals/transactions-v2

In the meantime, is there any way to reduce the number of unique addresses? For example, can Native Programs be referenced directly from on-chain programs (as hardcoded constants) or there is absolutely no exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to switching any syscall accesses to the [aforementioned](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/204/36) `Syscall::get()`. Consider breaking your operation up such that it can be performed with multiple transactions.  This typically requires driving an onchain state machine, which is a bit more complex, but has been used successfully since the early days of Solana program development.

EDIT: And yes, *all* referenced program addresses must be declared up front in the transaction, native or not

Answer (score 1):

As per https://docs.solana.com/developing/runtime-facilities/sysvars, the following sysvars *can* be accessed with a `::get()` call:

- Clock
- EpochSchedule
- Fees
- Rent

The rest need to be passed in.